# Linked Excel Documents in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Were migrating documents from a file server to sharepoint. We have a large set of docments that are linked and use macros. I understand this is not allowed in sharepoint online (linking documents) does anyone know of a solution or a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Excel macro-enabled workbooks (.xlsm) can be opened but macros [do not run in a browser window](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6).

There is no alternative way to use the macros in Excel Online. But the workbook will work just fine if you set the documents to open in client application by default.

Quoting the official [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-with-vba-macros-in-excel-for-the-web-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343):

> Although you can't create, run, or edit VBA (Visual Basic for
> Applications) macros in Excel for the web, you can open and edit a
> workbook that contains macros.  Any existing macros will remain in the
> workbook, and you can open the workbook in the Excel desktop app to
> view and edit the macros.

Comment: What about linked documents? That is honestly the issue the linking of documents.

Comment: @DickyDal Would you please share what issue you are referring to? If you mean the linked documents with the Excel workbooks, they will not be affected as source files.

Comment: The documents are currently linked on a file server. So say if someone updates a master document the macro tells it to update other documents. We want to do somthing like that on sharepoint online.

Comment: @DickyDal Yes, you are right. That would not work in Office Online, but technically will remain working if you use Office clients. I would suggest using OneDrive sync client instead of SharePoint document libraries in this situation.